# How to do a case insensitive file include (filter) in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a list of files that I want to select using FileTree (or other?) to iterate over. I need to filter them using a case INsensitive search. Not sure how do this. Suggestions?

```
def files = FileTree ('srcDirectory'){
  include 'mYfILeName.file'
  caseSensitive == false????
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
def files = fileTree('srcDirectory') {
    include { it.file.name.toLowerCase() == 'myfilename.file' }
}
```

For details see [build language reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3afileTree%28java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) and [Javadoc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html#include%28groovy.lang.Closure%29). Note that it's `project.fileTree`, not `project.FileTree`.